# TF Object Detection API Segmentation Fault

Tags: python, tensorflow, segmentation-fault, object-detection-api

I'm attempting to run the TF object detection API in the same way as I have multiple times in the past in other machines (same Dockerfile setup). This time, when trying to call `model_main.py`, all that is returned is `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

I stepped through `model_main.py` and found that this segfault occurs very early, in the line `from object_detection import model_lib`. How can I get to the bottom of why this is occurring? I have this core dump file, but I'm not sure how I can use this to figure out more about what caused this segfault. GPU/versions I'm using are:
Ubuntu 16.04
NVIDIA K80
CUDA 9.0
cuDNN 7.3.1
Python 3.6.7
Tensorflow 1.10

I'm also able to import TensorFlow without any issues and run this basic test I've found successfully:

```
import tensorflow as tf
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
    b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
    c = tf.matmul(a, b)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print (sess.run(c))
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

**Edit:** Sorta-kinda solved. In `model_lib.py`, the line that causes the error is `from object_detection import eval_util`. If I modify this file so that this line is the last import instead of one of the first, this segfault disappears. No idea why, so if anyone knows I'd be really interested in hearing.

Comment: Kindly post the entire error traceback. It's impossible to debug without it

Comment: I wish I had a longer error to go by, but my terminal only outputs that single line error. That's the first issue I'm having in trying to debug this.

Comment: I have the same issue.Were you able to figure out the root cause?

Comment: @SricharanKambhammettu It was due to running python 3 when the code was written in python 2. You can get it to work, but need to wrap range() objects with list() in a couple of places in the API code. Also if I remember correctly there was an incorrect importing order in one of the files.

Comment: Thanks. It worked after I made the said change..